# Initializing list with NULL has unexpected length

Tags: r, list, for-loop

```
dane = list(list(),list(),list())
for(n in 1:3){
  for(m in 1:6){
    dane[[n]][m] =c()
  }
}
lengths(dane)
# [1] 5 5 5
```

Why does the result have sublists of length 5, not 6?

More minimally:

```
x = list()
for(i in 1:3) x[i] = NULL
length(x)
# [1] 2
## why is this 2, not 3?
```

Comment: A version that works as expected: if you assign `list(NULL)` instead of `NULL` or `c()`, the lengths come out right. And since we are using `[` not `[[`, assigning a `list` makes a little more sense...

Comment: Actually `lapply` is working: `lapply(1:3, function(y) x[y] = NULL)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the loop, the elements actually get **deleted**, not `NULL` is stored in there. If you attempt to delete the *n*-th element of a list of zero length, a list with `NULL` elements is created up to the penultimate element.

Try

```
x <- list()

length(x)
# [1] 0

x[5] <- NULL

x
# [[1]]
# NULL
# 
# [[2]]
# NULL
# 
# [[3]]
# NULL
# 
# [[4]]
# NULL
```

where

```
length(x)
# [1] 4
```

To initialize a list with empty list elements recall that in R a list is also a vector.

```
li <- vector(mode='list', length=3L)
li
# [[1]]
# NULL
# 
# [[2]]
# NULL
# 
# [[3]]
# NULL
```